# How to Set WinForms Textbox to overwrite mode

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Is it possible to force a textbox in a windows forms application to work in "overwrite mode", i.e. have characters replaced when the user types instead of added?
Otherwise, is there a standard way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using a MaskedTextBox and set InsertKeyMode to InsertKeyMode.Overwrite.

```
MaskedTextBox box = ...;
box.InsertKeyMode = InsertKeyMode.Overwrite;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not wish to use a Masked textbox you can do this when handling the KeyPress event.

```
    private void Box_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox Box = (sender as TextBox);
        if (Box.SelectionStart < Box.TextLength && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            int CacheSelectionStart = Box.SelectionStart; //Cache SelectionStart as its reset when the Text property of the TextBox is set.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Box.Text); //Create a StringBuilder as Strings are immutable
            sb[Box.SelectionStart] = e.KeyChar; //Add the pressed key at the right position
            Box.Text = sb.ToString(); //SelectionStart is reset after setting the text, so restore it
            Box.SelectionStart = CacheSelectionStart + 1; //Advance to the next char
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard way would be to select the existing text as you land in the textbox, then as the user types it will automatically replace the existing text

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to have an error. I found that you need to set e.Handled in the Keypress event, otherwise the character is inserted twice. Here is my code (in VB) based on the above: -

```
Private Sub txtScreen_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtScreen.KeyPress
    If txtScreen.SelectionStart < txtScreen.TextLength AndAlso Not [Char].IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        Dim SaveSelectionStart As Integer = txtScreen.SelectionStart
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(txtScreen.Text)
        sb(txtScreen.SelectionStart) = e.KeyChar
        'Add the pressed key at the right position
        txtScreen.Text = sb.ToString()
        'SelectionStart is reset after setting the text, so restore it
        'Advance to the next char
        txtScreen.SelectionStart = SaveSelectionStart + 1
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. Found this helpful. I used this (after converting to C#).. (You know question was tagged for  C#) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `RichTextBox` instead of a `TextBox`.

Source:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/966c3af9-6674-4f48-b487-7afbef05f0cb/overwrite-mode-in-a-textbox

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all! this is mine now. ref :
https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/windowsforms/textbox/how-can-i-place-a-textbox-in-overwrite-mode-instead-of-insert-mode

```
int surrogate = 0;
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!insertMode)
    {
        if (char.IsSurrogate(e.KeyChar))
        {
            surrogate++;
            if (surrogate % 2 != 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            surrogate = 0;
        }
        if (textBox1.Text.Length != textBox1.MaxLength && textBox1.SelectedText == ""
           && textBox1.Text != "" && textBox1.SelectionStart != textBox1.Text.Length)
        {
            textBox1.SelectionLength = 1;//對於已經輸入完成的 surrogate C#應該會正確判斷其字長度；實際測試非然也
            //for surrogate pairs input this is necessary or it will cut the pairs in wrong way above
            if (char.IsSurrogate(textBox1.SelectedText.ToCharArray()[0]))
            {
                textBox1.SelectionLength = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my applied repo :
https://github.com/oscarsun72/TextForCtext.git

WindowsFormsApp1/Form1.cs

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if using the KeyPress event messes up the normal overtype process, or maybe something specific being checked for within KeyPress, but this isn't quite how a normal windows text box should behave, in that when you start typing in a control with highlighted text, the selection should be removed, allowing you to type in that emptied space. Once I saw the If statement I realised the behaviour I was looking for was accomplished doing this:

```
    If tb.SelectionStart < tb.TextLength AndAlso Not [Char].IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
        tb.SelectedText = ""
    End If
```

not sure why you would want to preserve the selection, but the previous code is ideal if that's what you need

Sal

Comment: That is clearly not what the OP was asking for and there is already a valid, accepted, and highly up-voted answer that proves it.

Comment: but didn't quite give me what i was looking for - yet this was the best response that Google gave me.... meaning if someone else comes looking for the same thing I'm looking for and finds this article their problem is solved

Comment: I understand, and I almost feel bad about down voting after your response. But in that case I would recommend posting a Q&A style question. Post a new question and answer it with this answer at the same time. Make the title exactly what you were searching for in google and there you go. You might find others have found alternative ways of doing it and people really appreciate your info and up-vote accordingly.

Comment: OK - thanks for the info - I'll try my hand at posting