# Custom caret in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, winforms-interop

I am working on c# datagridview project where I have to change the default caret to dos like caret. I have search the internet buy unable to find any solution . Any suggestions from the respective members.

Comment: Usually switching between insert and replace mode will switch the caret from line to block. Maybe you could replace the normal EditingControl (ie a TextBox) by a [MaskedTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428047/how-to-set-winforms-textbox-to-overwrite-mode)

Answer (score 1):

**To change the cursor using the Designer:**

1: Go to the designer and right-click your control.

2: In the right-click-menu go to Properties

3: In properties scroll down to Cursor and select the cursor you want.

**Or to change the cursor to a custom cursor:**

The function to change the cursor:

```
public static Cursor ActuallyLoadCursor(String path)
{
    return new Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(path));
}
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string fileName);
```

code from: [Custom cursor in C# Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638720/custom-cursor-in-c-sharp-winforms)

Call the function:

```
yourdatagrid.Cursor = ActuallyLoadCursor("PathToYourCursor.cur");
```

Also take a look at this folder to find a cursor:
**C:\Windows\Cursors**

Comment: I asked about caret not cursor